# mysql select empty fileds but exclude 0 valued fields

Tags: mysql

In a mysql database, I need to match records that have empty fields and replace them with NULL so I am running the following query:

`UPDATE table_name SET col_name=NULL WHERE col_name='';`

This works but it also matches fields with value 0, how can I change this query to match only empty fields and ignore fields with value 0 ? ..or maybe is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what is the datatype for the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the column is integer:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col_name=NULL WHERE LENGTH(col_name)=0;
```

Comment: Works great, Thanks! ...I'm running that on columns of different type actually as I need to ensure there are no empty fields anywhere.